# Problem while inserting webview inside the progress dialog for twitter

Tags: android, twitter, webview, progressdialog, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am trying to implement twitter sharing for my application in android 3.0.  I have used the progessdialog with webview inside it for the twitter login.  I am using browser type of application so that once i am successfully logged in, Twitter will send me to the callback url  which is of my webpage.  But when i logged in successfully it doesnt send me to my webpage neither does anything.

I also saw this warning in the console:
  "Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz."

I was wondering is there any problem while using webview with progressdialog in android 3.0 ??  Because this sharing is working fine with android 2.2.

Thanks in advance, aby